# How to display a 5-14 column table in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i have a requirement  where presently im displaying the  dynamic data using **ion-col** in that i m displaying column more than 8 Fields but it is not cumming responsive & here i require a suggestion how to display a table which have more than 5 max 14 fields using ionic 2

Answer (score 1):

By default Ionic 2 grid comes with a 12 columns pattern, you can change it using SASS ans styling guides

Here's a link to [Number of columns](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#number-of-columns-and-padding). What you need to do is simply add the following code in your `variables.scss` under `theme` folder:

```
$grid-columns: 14;
```

This will force your grid to have 14 columns instead of the default 12.

About the minimun of 5 columns there's no way to controll it, there's no minimun columns value, you'll need to proramatically assure that there's at least 5 columns, a way of doing this is using a total of columns that'll end up beeing represented in the screen as 5 columns, something like:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <!-- assuming you're using 14 columns, if you're not all col- attributes must be col-2 -->
    <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have maximum 14 columns requirement, then you need to do some customization.
Like, You have to divide 100% width by 14 (100/14= 7.14 %), Give width of 7.14% to the div or td you are using. and you will be able to manage 14 columns in your app.

```
 .div_width{
    width:7.14%;
    display:inline-block;
 }



 <ion-list>
   <ion-grid>
     <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 text-center>
          <div class="div_width">
            content here
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid> 
  </ion-list>
```